# C calling a class function inside of another Class that is currently an Object

Tags: c++, class, object

new here, so be gentle, I'm currently doing my Major Project for my course and, I'm not asking for homework to be done for me, i just can't wrap my head around a strange problem i am having and have not been able to find an answer for it, even on here. I'm using SDL for my Drawing.

I'm doing Object Orientated Programming with my Project or a "state Machine" (which sounds less painful in a newbies mind, believe me), and in the render part of my Class Game1.cpp i am trying to call a Draw Function of my Player Class, but for some unknown reason that i can not fathom, it just skips this function call completely.

I have no errors, i even used breakpoints to find out what was happening, but it just skipped it completely every time, it is drawing the screen black as well without fail. Any help as t why it is skipping this would be really appreciated.

I honestly feel like it's a simple rookie mistake, but any and all scrutiny is welcome of my code, anything i can do to better myself is appreciated.

Game1.cpp:

```
#include "Game1.h"
#include "PlayerCharacter.h"
Game1::Game1( World * worldObject )
{
    //object setup
    this->worldObject = worldObject;
    setDone (false);
}

Game1::~Game1()
{

}

void Game1::handle_events()
{
    //*******************************************
    //**//////////////Call Input///////////////**
    //*******************************************
    //******Check for Keyboard Input*************

    //******Check Keyboard Logic*****************

    //******Check for Mouse Input****************
    //The mouse offsets
    x = 0, y = 0;

    //If the mouse moved
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&worldObject->event))
    {
        if( worldObject->event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION )
        {
            //Get the mouse offsets
            x = worldObject->event.motion.x;
            y = worldObject->event.motion.y;
        }
    }
    //******Check Mouse Logic********************


}

void Game1::logic()
{



    //*******************************************
    //**//////////Collision Detection//////////**
    //*******************************************
    //******Check Player Bullet Collision Loop***
    //Check for collision with enemies

    //Check for collision with bitmap mask (walls)

    //******Check Enemy Bullet Collision Loop****
    //Check for Collision with Player

    //Check for collision with bitmap mask (walls)



}

void Game1::render()
{
    //*******************************************
    //**////////////////Drawing////////////////**
    //*******************************************
    //******Blit Black Background****************
    SDL_FillRect(worldObject->Screen , NULL , 0xff000000);

    //******Blit Bitmap Mask*********************

    //******Blit Flashlight**********************

    //******Blit Map*****************************

    //******Blit Pickups*************************

    //******Blit Bullets*************************

    //******Blit Player**************************
    &PlayerCharacter.Draw; // <----- Skips this line completely, no idea why

    //******Blit Enemies*************************

    //******Blit Blackened Overlay***************

    //******Blit HUD*****************************

    //******Flip Screen**************************
    SDL_Flip(worldObject->Screen);
}
```

Game1.h

```
#ifndef __Game1_H_INLUDED__
#define __Game1_H_INLUDED__

#include "GameState.h"
#include "SDL.h"
#include "ImageLoader.h"
using namespace IMGLoader;
class Game1 : public GameState
{
    private:
    //Menu Image
    World * worldObject;
    SDL_Rect PauseMenu,Item1Tile,Item2Tile,Item3Tile;
    /*bool bPauseMenu, bItem1Tile, bItem2Tile, bItem3Tile;
    int ButtonSpace,ButtonSize;
    float x,y;
    int Alpha1,Alpha2;*/
    //Clipping Window
    //SDL_Rect sclip,dclip;

    public:
    //Loads Menu resources
    Game1 (World * worldObject);
    //Frees Menu resources
    ~Game1();

    //Main loop functions
    void handle_events();
    void logic();
    void render();
};

#endif
```

PlayerCharacter.cpp

```
#include "PlayerCharacter.h"

SDL_Rect psclip,pdclip;

PlayerCharacter::PlayerCharacter ( float X, float Y, float dX, float dY, float Angle, float Speed, bool Existance, int Height, int Width, int Health, int Shield, SDL_Surface* Player ):Characters ( X, Y, dX, dY, Angle, Speed, Existance, Height, Width, Health )
{
    this->Player = Player;
    this->Shield = Shield;
    this->Player = load_image("image\Player1.png");
}
void PlayerCharacter::setShield ( int Shield )
{
    this->Shield = Shield;
}
int PlayerCharacter::getShield ( void )
{
    return Shield;
}
void PlayerCharacter::Draw(  ) 
{
    psclip.x = 0; psclip.y = 0; psclip.w = 64; psclip.h = 64;
    pdclip.x = 640; pdclip.y = 318; pdclip.w = 64; pdclip.h = 64;
    SDL_BlitSurface(Player, &psclip, worldObject->Screen, &pdclip);
}
```

PlayerCharacter.h

```
#ifndef __PlayerCharacter_H_INCLUDED__
#define __PlayerCharacter_H_INCLUDED__

#include "Characters.h"

class PlayerCharacter : public Characters
{
private:
    int Shield;
    SDL_Surface* Player;
    World *worldObject;
public:
    PlayerCharacter ( float X, float Y, float dX, float dY, float Angle, float Speed, bool Existance, int Height, int Width, int Health, int Shield, SDL_Surface* Player );

    void setShield ( int Shield );
    int getShield ( void );

    void Draw (  );
};

#endif
```

Comment: Hmmm.... too much code? Have you *tried* coming up with a [sscce](http://www.sscce.org) for your problem? I seriously doubt your programming problem is relying on all this SDL fluff to be demonstrated...

Comment: `&PlayerCharacter.Draw;` or `PlayerCharacter.Draw();` ?

Comment: &PlayerCharacter.Draw; is what it is now and     PlayerCharacter.Draw(); errors saying "a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object" Also     &PlayerCharacter::Draw; does not work which is what it was originally before i started experimenting.

Comment: `PlayerCharacter.Draw()` errors with that error message exactly because of what the error message says - you need a `PlayerCharacter` *object* to call this method on. Have you *understood* how classes, objects, and methods work? It appears not, and that is at the root of your problem I'm afraid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
&PlayerCharacter.Draw; // <----- Skips this line completely, no idea why
```

is not actually a function call. It's an expression that take the address of the `Draw` function in the `PlayerCharacter` class and does nothing with it.

I'm actually kind of surprised it compiles without errors, or at least tons of warnings.

You need to create a `PlayerCharacter` object, and then call the function in the object.

Comment: after reading your answear a 3rd time finnaly hit me what you were saying

Answer (score 1):

`&PlayerCharacter.Draw` is not a function call. `PlayerCharacter::Draw()` is not a static class method, so you need a `PlayerCharacter` *object* to invoke this method on.

You have a `class PlayerCharacter`, which defines what a `PlayerCharacter` *is* and what can be *done* with it. But as far as I see, you don't have a single `PlayerCharacter` *object*, i.e. no player character. If you had one, let's call him `pc`, then you could draw him with `pc.Draw()`. For that, you would have to *instantiate* the class, e.g. via `PlayerCharacter pc( ... )`, with the `...` replaced by some appropriate values for the multitude of constructor parameters you have there. (You really want a default constructor, initializing all those to zero or other appropriate "start" value...)

Comment: sorry about the amount of code there is, so your your saying i should create a second Object with the PlayerCharacter as it's active class to be able to use the function i want from the player Character class?

Comment: @ElliottBott: What I am saying is that your use of vocabulary hints at you not having understood the underlying concepts, which is why you should drop the SDL code and try your hand at some `ExampleClass` stuff first. No offense intended -- it's really the best thing to do.

Comment: @ElliottBott: With all the code you provided, you did *not* provide your `main()`, so as far as I can see, you don't have *any* objects to begin with. Just classes. ;-)

Comment: hehe, yeah but i understand now, thanks for the help, i thought i needed to have a second Object but was not sure, thank you again.